# Find Possible Combination with set of options without repetitions.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose I have the following items.

1. Apple
2. Mango
3. Orange
4. Pineapple

I want to find all possible combinations without repetitions. How do I find that?

Note: I have tried Permutations and Combinations, but its asking to provide a length. Its not working for me.

Here's the expected result.

```
Apple
Apple, Mango
Apple, Mango, Orange
Apple, Mango, Orange, Pineapple
Mango
Mango, Orange
Mango, Orange, Pineapple
Orange
Orange, Apple
Orange, Pineapple
Pineapple
Pineapple, Apple
Pineapple, Mango
Pineapple, Orange, Apple
```

Any ideas how to find this using a formula, or any online calculator available to find this?

Comment: Hint:  a set of order $n$ has $2^n$ subsets, including the empty set.

Comment: @lulu Can you explain more? What is it called? Any naming for this?

Comment: See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931117/prove-that-the-power-set-of-an-n-element-set-contains-2n-elements) for a proof of my claim.  Note:  your list only has $14$ elements while it should have $2^4-1=15$.  Indeed, you seem to have skipped Apple,Mango, Pineapple.