# Use Mathematical Induction to show that for any set $S$, If $\vert S\vert=n$, then $\vert\mathcal P(S)\vert=2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use Mathematical Induction to show that for any set $S$, If  $\vert S\vert = n$, then $\vert\mathcal P(S)\vert= 2^n$.

How would I approach this question?
What would the base case be when I apply it to the left hand side?

Comment: The base case is $n=0$.

Comment: I understand that the base case is n=0, but how would I apply that to the power set? How would you use the 0 to prove a case?

Comment: For $n=0$, $S=\emptyset$ and therefore $\mathcal P(S)=\{\emptyset\}$, which has $1$ element.

Comment: Then use induction as you suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the power set of an $n$-element set contains $2^n$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931117/prove-that-the-power-set-of-an-n-element-set-contains-2n-elements)

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546414/what-is-the-proof-that-the-total-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-is-2n